# How to save data from the User form that is implemented by built-in auth. User using UserCreationForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

Hi I am new to Django and I have created a login/logout model Django inbuilt User and UserCreationForm. It is working fine but my issue is I have define two custom inputs in my form and it is displaying on the web page when I run the server but when I check the user under the admin, I only see the details of User defined fields not my custom fields.

How to save it's data to my User model?
or maybe If I defined the custom fields wrong how do I change it so that I can save it's data in my model.

My custom defined fields that is address and phone number is not showing in Admin User and it's data is not getting saved.

## model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth
# Create your models here.
class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

## forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
class UserCreateform(UserCreationForm):

    address = forms.CharField(max_length=150, required=True)
    phone_number = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):

        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username','email','password1','password2')


        def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
            self.fields['username'].label = 'Display Name'
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from . import forms
# Create your views here.

class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateform
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'account/signup.html'
```

Comment: You need to have a model that has those fields. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). Those are the two options you have. Your `User` model is **wrong** you should never subclass `auth.User`, you should subclass `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`. I would advise you to **extend** the user model using a `Profile` model for the fields `address` and `phone_number` **and** subclass `AbstractUser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding fields to a `ModelForm` doesn't do anything in terms of saving them, if they are not fields of the `Model`. So of course, `address` and `phone_number` aren't saved, your `User` model doesn't have those fields.

You need to have a `Model` to save those fields. As explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), you have two options:

- Create a `Profile` model to save all extra fields
- Create a custom `User` model, subclassing `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`.

My advice: Do both. Save your extra fields in a `Profile` model.
**And** subclass `AbstractUser`, so you have the option to add useful methods and properties to the `User` model (right now, just `__str__()`).

Why not just subclass? Because as your app grows, you'll want to add more an more things to a user's profile. Maybe you want to create different types of profiles, e.g. the private profile and the professional profile. The `User` itself should be compact, just managing authentication and permissions.

**Note**: your current `User` model is **wrong**. You **must not** subclass `auth.User` but `auth.AbstractUser`.